# Why is Python printing my file directory has changed, but when I check through file manager, it hasn't changed?

Tags: python

I have a Python script, and I'm using `os.chdir`. I want to change my python file directory to the path below. My current code is:

```
        path = "C:\\Users\\Jalen\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"
        os.chdir(path)
```

I'm using `os.cwd()`after running that and it prints the new path the file is supposed to be in. However, when I look in the new path on file explorer, the python file isn't there. Any help? Sort of new to Python.

Comment: I think you get the functionality of those method all wrong. It's not method to create new folders but to configure the working directory of your code. Maybe you'r looking for `mkdir()`

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Im not trying to make a new directory. Im trying to move the python file to an already existing directory, but It won't change.

Comment: You must explain your purpose in the question. Are you trying to move the file your code is running from? Please edit your question and explain your goal accurately.

Comment: `os.chdir` changes *the working directory* not the directory where the file is located.

Comment: Use `shutil.copy`, you are mostly likely following wrong approach.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to move the file my code is running from to a new directory.

Comment: If you're just trying to move files then you should make use of `shutil`. `shutil.move(path/new/destination/of_file, path/old/destination/of_file)` this should move what ever file you want to whatever directory you specify

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` just change the directory it working on. You should try this:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Jalen\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"
itself = open(__file__, 'r').readline()
new = open(path, 'w+')
for line in itself:
    new.write(line)
```